# Why I could setup SSL connection to RDS without a certificate file?

Tags: ssl, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

I have an Aurora Postgresql instance in AWS RDS with encryption enabled.

According to the document, in order to setup a SSL connection with the RDS instance, I downloaded the rds-ca-2019.pem,and using psql command to setup the connection:

```
psql "host=xxx  dbname=xxx -p 5432 user=xxx sslrootcert=rds-ca-2019.pem sslmode=verify-full"
```

After providing the password, I could setup a SSL connection without an issue. But what I do not understand is that even if I do not provide the sslrootcert, and using the following command, the connection is still SSL, why is that?

```
psql "host=xxx  dbname=xxx -p 5432 user=xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to provide the certificate file if you want `psql` to verify the server's SSL certificate. In other words, you only need to provide the certificate file if you specify `sslmode=verify-full`.

Since you didn't specify that SSL mode in your second command, `psql` is happy to create an SSL connection to the server without verifying the server's certificate.